# Simple Ruby average program

Tags: ruby

I'm computing average for 3 numbers that users will input in Ruby. Every time I run the app, the user puts in 3 numbers but I get an error stating:

> test.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method`/' for "23\n23\n24\n":String (NoMethodError)

My code is as follows:

```
puts "Enter first"
num1 = gets
puts "Enter second"
num2 = gets
puts "Enter third"
num3 = gets
avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3
puts "Average is  " + avg
```

Comment: You need to examine error messages carefully. Often, as here, they pinpoint the problem. This one tells you the method `/` is not defined for the instance `"23\n23\n24\n"` of the class `String`. That means `(num1 + num2 + num3)` is a string (not an integer). You therefore need to change it to `(num1.to_i + num2.to_i + num3.to_i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Ruby, but if it's similar to Python you'll have to convert the input you get from a string to an integer. Right now your program is just concatenating the strings you enter, and gets confused because you cannot use `/` on strings.

Edit: you'll have to use the method `.to_i` on the input to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
puts "Enter first"
num1 = gets.to_i
puts "Enter second"
num2 = gets.to_i
puts "Enter third"
num3 = gets.to_i
avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3.0
puts "Average is #{avg}"
```

First, you need to strip the newline from your gets method and convert the string to an integer by calling [`.to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i). Then, to properly output the average, just use string interpolation.

Comment: Actually there is no need to call `chomp`, when you plan to call `to_i` anyway. From the docs: _Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned._ Just remove the `chomp`, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @spickermann, you are totally right. I updated my answer to reflect your input. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You for explaining it Alex, I still have one more question. I'm still a beginner in Ruby so I don't quite understand the #{avg} part. Is that the only way to compute average in Ruby? There isn't another way for beginners? I just don't want to get ahead of myself.

Comment: @JohnDoe, when you had `puts "Average is " + avg`, it would throw this error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`. This is due to the fact that you are trying to concatenate a string with a number. To get the desired output ("Average is n"), you would need to use string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

`gets` returns a `String`, not a number. Therefore you need to call `to_i` on it first.

Furthermore: To return a `Float` your calculation needs to have a float value on the left or the right side of the `/` otherwise it would return an `Integer` (what might be unexpected):

```
(1 + 1 + 2) / 3
#=> 1
(1 + 1 + 2) / 3.0
#=> 1.3333333333333333
```

Change your code to:

```
puts "Enter first"
num1 = gets.to_i
puts "Enter second"
num2 = gets.to_i
puts "Enter third"
num3 = gets.to_i
avg = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3.0
puts "Average is #{avg}"
```

Comment: What is the meaning of #{avg}? There is no other way to compute average?

Comment: @JohnDoe The `"... #{avg} ..."` is a string interpolation and a common Ruby idiom. It is basically the same as `"... " + avg.to_s + " ..."`. It has the advantage the it is less error-prone than to concat Strings with `+`, because it calls `to_s` automatically, and many [devs](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation) think it is easier to read.